# How to generate a lazy division?

Tags: raku, lazy-sequences

I want to generate the sequence of

```
1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 ... *
```

using functional programming  approach in raku, in my head it's should be look like:

`(1,{1/$_} ...*)[0..5`]

but the the output is: 1,1,1,1,1
The idea is simple, but seems enough powerful for me to using to generate for other complex list and work with it.

Others things that i tried are using a lazy list to call inside other lazy list, it doesn't work either, because the output is a repetitive sequence: 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5 ...

```
my list = 0 ... *;
(1, {1/@list[$_]} ...*)[0..5]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See @wamba's wonderful answer for solutions to the question in your title. They showcase a wide range of applicable Raku constructs.

This answer focuses on Raku's sequence operator (`...`), and the details in the body of your question, explaining what went wrong in your attempts, and explaining some working sequences.

## TL;DR

The value of the `N`th term is `1 / N`.

```
# Generator ignoring prior terms, incrementing an N stored in the generator:
{ 1 / ++$ } ... *                               # idiomatic
{ state $N; $N++; 1 / $N } ... *                # longhand

# Generator extracting denominator from prior term and adding 1 to get N:
1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/(*.denominator+1) ... *        # idiomatic (@jjmerelo++)
1/1, 1/2, 1/3, {1/(.denominator+1)} ... *       # longhand (@user0721090601++)
```

## What's wrong with `{1/$_}`?

```
1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 ... *
```

What is the value of the `N`th term? It's `1/N`.

```
1, {1/$_} ...*
```

What is the value of the `N`th term? It's `1/$_`.

`$_` is a generic *parameter/argument/operand* analogous to the English pronoun "it".

Is it set to `N`?

No.

So your generator (lambda/function) doesn't encode the sequence you're trying to reproduce.

## What is `$_` set to?

Within a function, `$_` is bound either to `(Any)`, or to an argument passed to the function.

If a function explicitly specifies its *parameters* (a "parameter" specifies an argument that a function *expects to receive*; this is distinct from the argument that a function actually ends up getting for any given call), then `$_` is bound, or not bound, per that specification.

If a function does *not* explicitly specify its parameters -- and yours doesn't -- then `$_` is bound to the argument, if any, that is passed as part of the call of the function.

For a *generator* function, any value(s) passed as arguments are *values of preceding terms in the sequence*.

Given that your generator doesn't explicitly specify its parameters, the immediately prior term, if any, is passed and bound to `$_`.

In the *first* call of your generator, when `1/$_` gets evaluated, the `$_` is bound to the `1` from the first term. So the second term is `1/1`, i.e. `1`.

Thus the *second* call, producing the third term, has the same result. So you get an infinite sequence of `1`s.

## What's wrong with `{1/@list[$_+1]}`?

For your last example you presumably meant:

```
my @list = 0 ... *;
(1, {1/@list[$_+1]} ...*)[0..5]
```

In this case the *first* call of the generator returns `1/@list[1+1]` which is `1/2` (`0.5`).

So the *second* call is `1/@list[0.5+1]`. This specifies a fractional index into `@list`, asking for the `1.5`th element. Indexes into standard `Positional`s are rounded down to the nearest integer. So `1.5` is rounded down to `1`. And `@list[1]` evaluates to `1`. So the value returned by the second call of the generator is back to `1`.

Thus the sequence alternates between `1` and `0.5`.

## What arguments are passed to a generator?

Raku passes the value of zero or more prior terms in the sequence as the arguments to the generator.

How many? Well, a generator is an ordinary Raku lambda/function. Raku uses the implicit or explicit declaration of parameters to determine how many arguments to pass.

For example, in:

```
{42} ... * # 42 42 42 ...
```

the lambda doesn't declare what parameters it has. For such functions Raku presumes a signature including `$_?`, and thus passes the prior term, if any. (The above lambda ignores it.)

## Which arguments do you *need/want* your generator to be passed?

One could argue that, for the sequence you're aiming to generate, you don't need/want to pass *any* of the prior terms. Because, arguably, *none* of them really matter.

From this perspective all that matters is that the `N`th term computes `1/N`. That is, its value is independent of the values of prior terms and just dependent on *counting the number of calls*.

## State solutions such as `{1/++$}`

One way to compute this is something like:

```
{ state $N; $N++; 1/$N } ... *
```

The lambda ignores the previous term. The net result is just the desired `1 1/2 1/3 ...`.

(Except that you'll have to fiddle with the stringification because by default it'll use `gist` which will turn the `1/3` into `0.333333` or similar.)

Or, more succinctly/idiomatically:

```
{ 1 / ++$ } ... *
```

(An anonymous `$` in a statement/expression is a simultaneous declaration and use of an anonymous state scalar variable.)

## Solutions using the prior term

As @user0721090601++ notes in a comment below, one can write a generator that makes use of the prior value:

```
1/1, 1/2, 1/3, {1/(.denominator+1)} ... *
```

For a generator that doesn't explicitly specify its parameters, Raku passes the value of the prior term in the sequence as the argument, binding it to the "it" argument `$_`.

And given that there's no explicit invocant for `.denominator`, Raku presumes you mean to call the method on `$_`.

---

As @jjmerelo++ notes, an idiomatic way to express many lambdas is to use the explicit pronoun "whatever" instead of "it" (implicit or explicit) to form a [`WhateverCode` lambda](https://docs.raku.org/type/WhateverCode):

```
1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/(*.denominator+1) ... *
```

You drop the braces for this form, which is one of its advantages. (You can also use multiple "whatevers" in a single expression rather than just one "it", another part of this construct's charm.)

This construct typically takes some getting used to; perhaps the biggest hurdle is that a `*` must be combined with a "`WhateverCode`able" operator/function for it to form a `WhateverCode` lambda.

Comment: If one wanted to work iteratively off an initial value, then `1/1, { 1 / (*.denominator + 1) } ... *` would work too

Comment: @user0721090601, almost, without the curlies: (1/1,  1 / (*.denominator + 1)  ... *)[0..5]

Comment: Excellent point @user0721090601. :) I've rewritten my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: jjmerelo: indeed :-)  I was thinking too quickly while on mobile

Comment: I learned a lot, thanks for taking part of your time for explaining what's wrong with my code, it's very useful and think that your wonderful answer and the answer of @wamba are very clear and idiomatic ways to do even more complex list

Answer (score 14):

[TIMTOWTDI](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-TIMTOWTDI)

[routine `map`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/map)

```
(1..*).map: 1/*
```

[List repetition operator `xx`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/xx)

```
1/++$ xx *
```

[The cross metaoperator, `X`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-X_(cross_metaoperator)) or [the zip metaoperator `Z`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Zip_metaoperator)

```
1 X/ 1..*
1 xx * Z/ 1..*
```

[(Control flow) control flow gather `take`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/gather%20take#(Control_flow)_control_flow_gather_take_gather_take)

```
gather for 1..* { take 1/$_ }
```

[(Seq) method `from-loop`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/from-loop#(Seq)_method_from-loop)

```
Seq.from-loop: { 1/++$ }
```

[(Operators) infix `...`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/...#(Operators)_infix_...)

```
1, 1/(1+1/*) ... *
{1/++$} ... *
```

Comment: TIY `Seq.from-loop`.  I <3 Raku.  The beauty is i can see use cases / justification for each one of these

Comment: Woaaaaaa this is wonderful, is a way more than i expected for answers. I learned a lot, the list operators are even not on my watch to do this